# Is it necessary to set width&height attributes in base64 html-email?

Tags: html, email, base64, html-email

As far as I know width&height attributes are used in html emails to save email layout in case when images were not downloaded.
But if I use the whole base64 email (not only images encoded in base64, but also texts, structure or whatever it includes) is there any chance that images will be somehow switched off?

Comment: Probably not.. but it's probably still best to set the attributes. Images could be turned off, for example, or there could be a quick flicker if images are rendered late

Answer (score 0):

No it's not necessary to set the `height` attribute. In fact, it's more mobile-friendly if you don't (at least for now).

Something like this will make the an image go full width (but not past it's actual width), and scale down while keeping its proportion.

```
<img src="" width="600" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
```

This works everywhere. Apple Mail. Mobile Gmail. Desktop Outlook. etc. Works for base64 images or remotely referenced images alike.